# Как сделать считывание и проверку на наличие определенной роли участника сервера?

Tags: python, discord.py

Я уже написал код который должен это делать но выходит ошибка.

Код:

```
@bot.command()
async def reserv(ctx, comm:int):
    vip=False
    member = ctx.author
    role = member.roles
    if "1143125771603419217" in role:
        vip=True
    if vip == False:
        cena = int(comm * 15)
        em = discord.Embed(title="**Заказ:**", description=f"**Отлично! К оплате {cena} ₽**"
                                                           + "\n\n**Способы оплаты: **"
                                                             "\n**Сбер: 2202 2023 2127 
                                                              2225**"
                                                             "\n*Вскоре появятся новые 
                                                              способы.*"
                                                             "\n\n**После оплаты напишите 
                                                               владельцу с 
                                                               доказательствами.** 
                                                               *creeper_kriper*",
                                                                color=0x1f8b4c)
        await ctx.author.send(embed=em)

    if vip == True:
        cena = int(comm * 15)
        cena = cena/100*90
        em = discord.Embed(title="**Заказ:**", description=f"**Отлично! К оплате {cena} ₽**"
                                                           + "\n\n**Способы оплаты: **"
                                                             "\n**Сбер: **"
                                                             "\n*Вскоре появятся новые 
                                                               способы.*"
                                                             "\n\n**После оплаты напишите 
                                                               владельцу с 
                                                               доказательствами.** 
                                                              *creeper_kriper*",
                                                               color=0x1f8b4c)
        await ctx.author.send(embed=em)
```

Ошибка:

```
[2023-08-22 08:24:56] [ERROR   ] discord.ext.commands.bot: Ignoring exception in command reserv
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\matve\Desktop\CreeperBot 1.0\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 235, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\matve\Desktop\CreeperBot 1.0\main.py", line 37, in reserv
    role = member.roles
AttributeError: 'User' object has no attribute 'roles'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\matve\Desktop\CreeperBot 1.0\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 1350, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\matve\Desktop\CreeperBot 1.0\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 1029, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)  # type: ignore
  File "C:\Users\matve\Desktop\CreeperBot 1.0\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 244, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'User' object has no attribute 'roles'
```

Comment: Похоже что у объекта `User` (переменная `member`) нет свойства `roles`, вы точно уверены что вы обратились к правильному объекту/свойству?

Comment: А есть какие-то еще объекты к которым можно обратиться как к User?

Comment: Возможно вам поможет [этот вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70992066/how-to-get-message-author-id-in-discord-py-discord-python) с английского SO.

Comment: Опять же, там есть способ получения ID участника, но не получение его ролей. @ΝNL993

Comment: Там показывается способ как получить роль участника с помощью ID.

Comment: Попробуйте использовать это, может, поможет: user = ctx.guild.get_member(ctx.author.id)

Comment: новая ошибка discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_member'. @ΝNL993

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если делать выводы по ошибкам, которые вы привели в вопросе и комментарии, то можно предположить, что выполнение команды происходит в личных сообщениях с ботом, поэтому `ctx.author` возвращает вам объект класса [`User`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#id1).

Попробуйте сделать вот так:

```py
import discord

from discord.ext import commands


bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='.')


@bot.command()
async def reserv(ctx: commands.Context, comm: int):
    # Получаем объект класса `Guild`
    # Вместо параметра guild_id, нужно написать ID сервера
    guild = bot.get_guild(guild_id)
    # Получаем объект класса `Member`
    member = guild.get_member(ctx.author.id)
    # Получаем объект класса `Role` с необходимой ролью
    # Вместо параметра role_id, нужно вписать ID нужной вам роли
    role = member.get_role(role_id)
    
    # Аналогично из вашего кода, если vip == False
    if role not in member.roles:
        ...
    # Если vip == True
    else:
        ...
```

Comment: хорошая теория, но ошибка та же discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_member' (может быть я чтото не импортировал)? мои импорты: import asyncio
import discord
from discord.ui import View, Button
from discord.utils import get
from discord import *
from discord.ext import tasks, commands

Comment: @Creeper22398, вы заменили параметр `guild_id` на ID сервера?

Comment: Просто если судить по ошибке, в переменную `guild` вернулось значение `None`, поэтому и появляется ошибка

Comment: @Creeper22398, если данный ответ вам помог, пожалуйста нажмите на галочку напротив него =)